# Can you return a function that's based on a generic type?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm writing a simple proof of concept for what should be, in essence, a parser generator.

Basically I'm looking for a way that I can write a function that will return a function that converts from a string to some object of a given type - I want to be able to do the following in essence:

```
Func<string, double> ConvertToDouble = BuildConverter(typeof(0.0));
```

Obviously this is a pretty contrived example - but if I can do the simple version then I ought to be able to do the more complicated version!

FWIW, what I'm ultimately trying to do is to map a string of values onto a class, but to make it as flexible as possible, I want to do it by having a function that will return a function that does the conversion. In functional terms, I think I want something that looks like this:

```
a -> (string -> a)
```

As a first try, I've tried doing this:

```
public static Func<string, T> BuildParser<T>(T t)
    {
      if (t is String)
        return new Func<string, T>(x => x.ToString());
      if (t is double)
        return new Func<string, T>(x => double.Parse(x));
    }
```

Which doesn't work at all, but it leaves me feeling a bit stuck as to what approach I ought to be taking - so any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of generics if you are looking for _types_ in your generic function.

Comment: If you want run-time decisions, then you shouldn't use generics.  If you want compile-time decisions, then you shouldn't use "is".

Comment: @Oded - I'm not sure I agree, I'm just looking for a particular type of Type polymorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix `class` with `struct` types. Beyond that, it will work.

See the code below:

```
private void Testing() {
    var func = BuildParserStruct<double>();
    double value = func("5");
}

public static Func<string, T> BuildParserClass<T>() where T : class
{
    return x => x as T;
}

public static Func<string, T> BuildParserStruct<T>() where T : struct
{
    return (x => (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(double)));
}
```

Comment: That looks interesting! I'll give that a try - I'd totally forgotten about the 'where T:' syntax.

Comment: What makes you think that you can't "mix `class` with `struct` types"? This can be done with a single `BuildParser<T>` method; you don't need separate `BuildParserClass<T>` and `BuildParserStruct<T>` methods if you don't want to. (See my answer for an example.)

Comment: Fair enough. What I should have said is that a generic method cannot instantiate both struct and class types (or derived types) without using reflection. This limitation does not affect your solution, since your generic method does not instantiate anything... I've found your solution to be clever, even if limited (would need a cache of 30 items when dealing with 30 different types, and so on)...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want specific behaviors verified at compile time.  Why not just call [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or write individual methods to use?  All that your if statements accomplish is to take role of the programmer who should be chosing the appropriate conversion method.

If you want behaviors chosen at runtime, you should return `Func<string, object>`, and make the method non-generic.

The issue with using a generic Type T in the method is that T is fixed for each call to the method, and the logic in the method supposes T to vary in a single call (in one case T is a string, in another case T is a decimal).  The compiler cannot sort this out - it would need to allow both returnable instances to have the same type.

Comment: You're correct in so far as my example goes - it is just a proof of concept though. Ultimately, I've got a messaging system that sends messages as comma delimited strings, and each message can be mapped on to a class (or a struct). This means that whenever someone writes an app here that uses that messages system, they need to hand code how they map it to the class. What I want to do is, in essence, automate that by writing a mapper-generator as it were.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain of exactly what you're trying to do, but would something like this help?

```
var stringParser = GetParser<string>();
string s = stringParser("test");

var doubleParser = GetParser<double>();
double d = doubleParser("42");

// ...

public static Func<string, T> GetParser<T>()
{
    return (Func<string, T>)_parserCache[typeof(T)];
}

private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _parserCache =
    new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>
        {
            { typeof(string), new Func<string, string>(x => x) },
            { typeof(double), new Func<string, double>(x => double.Parse(x)) }
            // etc
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

ADO.Net has an Execute Scalar function that always bothered me because it returns an object.  You can write a generic wrapper function to return the appropriate type.  Of course this assumes that you know what type will be returned.

Somewhat simplified:

```
    public T ExecuteScalar<T>()
    {
        return (T)Command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
```